# Accessing array when passed to subroutine as reference in Perl

Tags: perl, pass-by-reference

I have misunderstanding, in using curly brackets in Perl with references. 
I've built a basic function to check if array contains a value.

**Example 1:**

```
sub array_contains
{
    my ($arr_ref, $search, $strict) = @_;
    if ($strict) {
        return (grep {$_ eq $search} @$arr_ref);
    } else {
        return grep {index($_, $search) != -1} @$arr_ref;
    }
}
```

Later, I wanted to make it look more concise.

**Example 2:**

```
sub array_contains
{
    return (!$_[2] ? 
       (grep {$_ eq $_[1]} @{$_[0]}) : 
       (grep {index($_, $_[1]) != -1} @{$_[0]})
    );
}
```

Then, it took me some time to realize that I can't use `@$_[0]` for some reason, like in the first example, and have to go with `@{$_[0]}`.

---

Could *Perl* experts please explain, why does it have to be on the second example `@{$_[0]}` and can't be `@$_[0]`, just like in the first example, where I used `@$arr_ref`. Does it have to do anything with assigning `@_` to the locally scoped variables?

Comment: Your "more concise" version is also much more unreadable. Doing that to your code has no advantages at all, so don't.

Comment: @Borodin, thanks. I will have this point in mind for the future.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The way to think about this is that the dereferencing "operator" has higher "precedence" than the array indexing (using quotes here because dereferencing isn't officially part of Perl's [operator precedence table](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Operator-Precedence-and-Associativity)).

```
use warnings;
use strict;

my $foo = ['arrayref elem 0','arrayref elem 1'];
my @foo = (['array of arrayrefs elem 0',' one']);

print  @$foo[0] , "\n";  # prints "arrayref elem 0"

# is the same as
print @{$foo}[0], "\n";  # prints "arrayref elem 0"

# is NOT the same as
print @{$foo[0]}, "\n";  # prints "array of arrayrefs elem 0 one"
```

That is, in the first two examples, first the array reference stored in `$foo` is dereferenced as an array, and *then* that array is indexed with `[0]` (although that's using [slice](http://perldoc.perl.org/perldata.html#Slices) syntax, `$$foo[0]` and `${$foo}[0]` would make more sense here). Only in the last example is the array `@foo` element `[0]` accessed *first*, and *then* that element is dereferenced as an array, resulting in all the elements of that array being printed. The behavior is the same for `$_`/`@_`.

See also [Using References in perlref](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlref.html#Using-References): the `@{...}` style of dereferencing always works, while the braces can *only* be omitted in simple cases, such as your `@$arr_ref`.

If you have Perl 5.24 or newer, you can make use of the [Postfix Dereference Syntax](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlref.html#Postfix-Dereference-Syntax) (it was [experimental](https://metacpan.org/pod/experimental) in 5.20 and 5.22):

```
use 5.024;
my @bar = (['Hello,',' World!']);
print $bar[0]->@*, "\n";  # prints "Hello, World!"
```

Answer (score 2):

Prefix dereference operators as in `@$arr` or `@$_[0]` bind very tightly – so the latter is parsed as `@{ $_ }[0]`. This is an *array slice*, which uses `$_` as an array reference. This is unrelated to the `@_` array. A slice of one element would usually be written as a scalar access `${ $_ }[0]` or `$_->[0]`.

Because prefix dereference operators parse confusingly, I recommend the postfix dereference syntax that is available since Perl 5.24. Then `@{ $_[0] }` can be written as `$_[0]->@*`.

Note that code should be *clear*, which is not necessarily the same as *short*. Naming your arguments instead of accessing the `@_` array directly is much more maintainable. I only access `@_` directly if there's only one argument (e.g. in an accessor method `sub foo { shift->{foo} }`) or when I benchmarked the code and have determined that avoiding a copy will save me half a microsecond that I really need. (Doesn't happen very often.)

If the goal of your function is a boolean check rather than selecting all matching elements, I'd write it like this:

```
use List::Util 'any';

sub array_contains {
  my ($arr, $search, $is_strict) = @_;
  return any { $_ eq $search } @$arr if $is_strict;
  return any { -1 != index $_, $search } @$arr;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I really don't want to use dependencies.

Comment: `List::Util` is a core module

Comment: Yeah, right, it's in the core since 5.007003. Thanks again!